# Handling ADODB.Connection.Close in OLE DB provider

Tags: oledb, ado

I implementing OLE DB provider for my custom database. It will be used from ADO applications.
Now i have ADO example which creates ADO connection then close it with Connection.Close method but not release interface pointer of connection object. After that sample application creates another connection object and fails to open it because first connection object does not release system resources required to create connection.

Obviously i need to release system resource when sample application calls Connection.Close method. But i cannot find OLE DB Interface::Method which is responsible for handling ADO Connection.Close. I thought IDBInitialize::Unintialize is responsible for that. But it is not. I am sure IDBInitialize::Unintialize is not called when cliaent application calls Connection.Close.

Please give me some advice about how to intercept Connection.Close in my OLE DB provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. When Connection.Close method is called ADO releases all its references to OLE DB session object.